# Adobe Air on IOS integrate Facebook Login Graph API

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a button on the stage and the name of the instance of the button on the stage is "btn" but when i run the app i can't seem to fire the touch event.

What i am trying to do is integrate Facebook Graph API login to the Adobe Air Application for iOS.

Anyway the code is below

please could you tell me where i am going wrong and what is missing.

Once the user logins i need to pull the user profile information and profile image.

### CODE

```
            import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.*;
import flash.media.Camera;
import flash.media.CameraUI;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.*;  
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.display.Sprite;

import com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile;
//import com.facebook.graph.windows;


 var vidCon:Video = new Video();
 const APP_ID:String = "299210093578823";
 var extendedPermissions:Array = ["publish_stream","user_website","user_status","user_about_me"];

Main();

 function Main() {
    // constructor code
    trace("main loaded");
    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit);
     //btn.enabled = false;                            
        btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,onFBLoginClick);
 }

 function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
    if (success){ 
        trace("Already logged in");
    }
    else{  
        //btn.enabled = true;
        trace("Not logged in-");
    }
}

 function onFBLoginClick(e:TouchEvent):void
{
          trace("ddddd");     
         var  webView = new StageWebView();
     webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
    FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,webView, extendedPermissions);
}
//--the below function dosnt seem to be getting called--
 function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
    if (success){
        trace("Logged In\n");
    }
    else{
        trace("Login Failed\n");
    }

    if(fail){
            trace("failed");
    }
}

 function onLogout(success:Boolean):void {
    trace("Log out");
}
```

Comment: do you get the ddddd trace? and why don't you just use MouseEvent.CLICK ?

Comment: @zavr, thanks. I changed it to mouse event and dddd trace is outputting but nothing seems to be happening at this line FacebookMobile.login(onLogin,webView, extendedPermissions);

Comment: there isn't much sources on lie available to help

Comment: check here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424101/as3-facebook-api-1-8-facebookmobile-login

Comment: @zavr, the code seems to work now the Facebook login appears i sign in then i need to redirect back to the app again but all it does is displays a success and Facebook information about security

Comment: I guess you need to close the StageWEbView. Do you get Logged In trace (by the way you don't need \n in trace)? if so, do webView = null or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56700/discussion-between-redoc01-and-zavr).